# add confidence interval to summary output in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary, confidence-interval

I am running a linear regression model, using stepwise selection procedure and would like to get the confidence intervals in the summary table. How can i do this ? The purpose is to be able to use `xtable` to use the output in Latex

```
step.model <- stepAIC(full.model,direction = "both",trace = FALSE)  
summary(step.model)
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i found the answer already

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution:

```
 # add confidence interval to table
    ci <- confint(step.model)
    sum_step.model <- (cbind(Estimate = coef(sum_step.model), ci))

#print results to latex
xtable(sum_step.model)
```